# Installing gr-gsm with PyBombs

Tags: python, linux, gnuradio

So I've been using the guide found [here](https://github.com/ptrkrysik/gr-gsm/wiki/Installation) to install gr-gsm for GNU Radio with pybombs on Arch Linux. However, when I get to the line for installing gr-gsm, I get the following error:

```
[josh@localhost ~]$ pybombs install gr-gsm
PyBombs.DepManager - ERROR - Package does not exist: ssl (declared as dependency for package libevent)
```

According to the guide, it should install dependencies by itself. I've gone through the documentation for pybombs to see if I'm doing something incorrectly and couldn't find anything. I double checked the configuration as well.

If I go into Python and import ssl, it's there.

EDIT:
Checking the recipe list, ssl is in there:

```
[josh@localhost build]$ pybombs recipes list

...

ssl                     ~/.pybombs/recipes/gr-recipes/ssl.lwr
```

and yet, I get the same error:

```
[josh@localhost build]$ pybombs install gr-gsm
PyBombs.DepManager - ERROR - Package does not exist: python (declared as dependency for package mako)
```

Comment: wait, you're not getting the *same* error; the first time, ssl is missing, the second it's python

Comment: Oops, I copy/pasted the wrong one. Sorry, I got to uninstalling and reinstalling a bunch of stuff yesterday. I can confirm that it is once again saying ssl is the missing package

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the verbatim output, and not something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It can not find the package. Actually it's the same on Void. It's a pitfall of all these wrap arounds. Because the package managers of Arch (fixed by now if I read the sources of Pybombs correctly), Void are not coded ...

You can edit `~/.pybombs/recipes/gr-recipes/ssl.lwr` and add a check yourself. If you add a new key then the code also needs changing if it is not considered in the sources.

But first check if you have SSL installed locally, e.g. using `pkg-config openssl --version`.

You can also flag the SSL check as optional during dependency check and then make sure it really exists and that it will be found by the compiler (which is invoked later).

Though for Arch this should be fixed by now.
[A nicer way for Arch instead of such wrappers like pybombs are PKGBUILDS - the same is true for Void who uses almost same format templates as Arch. A cross platform system like `0install` might also help.]

Edit: GNURadio exists as Arch package already, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Radio